# How to disable sharing/cast from Ubuntu

Tags: network-manager, sharing, purge, systemd-networkd

while watching a video on YouTube, there’s a cast button on bottom right which casts my Content to smart home devices like Alexa or Google home.
Which package on Ubuntu is responsible for it and how do I disable network discovery?
I tried the following

```
sudo apt purge avahi-daemon
sudo apt remove cups-browsed
```

Comment: Can you post a  screenshot , cast can sometime be a apart of the web browser your on

Comment: What leads you to believe that it's an Ubuntu package?

Comment: It’s a browser functionality but I believe there’s a way to disable it

Comment: tell us which browser & please add a screenshot as asked

Comment: Unable to add screenshot due to reputation less than 15. Look for the cast symbol on your YouTube app or browser when you play a video

Comment: Name your app that  you are using